# Отображение на Github файлов Python в одну строку

Tags: python, github

Объясните почему файлы на Github отображаются в одну строчку.
Было всё хорошо. Может после обновления PyCharm файлы стали отображаться в строчку.
Хочу исправить и вернуть отображение по строчкам, чтобы видеть изменения.

Пример с Github
[image: Пример с Github]

Этот же файл в PyCharm
[image: Этот же файл в PyCharm]

Comment: возможно гитхаб пытается тратить меньше памяти, поэтому он минимизирует код, но как исправить не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в ***line separators***

В самом ***PyCharm*** в правом нижнем углу есть значок ***LF***,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где вы можете поменять ***line separator***, по умолчанию там стоит **CRLF**, он скорее всего и выдает **^M**,попробуйте поменять и запушить.
Но это для каждого файла индивидуально.

Если же Вы хотите поменять полностью везде, то так:

- Зайдите в настройки PyCharm:
  ***Preferences ->>> Editor ->>> Code Style ->>> General ->>> Line Separator***

Comment: Здравствуйте Дмитрий. Спасибо большое за подсказку, вместе с ней получилось довольно быстро разобраться. Ход моих мыслей двигался в правильном направлении и Ваша помощь оказалась весьма кстати. 

Хочу заметить, что изменения в настройках **Line Separator**  изменили поведение новых файлов Python в PyCharm. А файлы которые были запушены ранее и отображались не корректно удалось изменить после создания **Create Gist…**